# Reports show location from Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hi
i get longitude and latitude from google maps using google maps aPI in my database. now i want to show the location name in reports. instead of longitude and latitude
I| am using Telerik reports
How can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding for an explanation of how to use Google Maps API to convert a Lat/Lng to a human-readable address.